# Throw front end error and Send Email in the same Apex transaction

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, email

Throwing AuraHandledException will stop email from being sent, so that I can't throw AuraHandledException to alert LWC and send a email in the same transaction.

My option will be either
a) separating the call into 2 sequential calls.
b) sending a custom message instead of throwing exception.

Did I miss anything or do you think there's a better approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Publish a Platform event using "Publish Immediate" - this will not be rolled back.   Use a Flow or Apex Trigger to subscribe to the Platform Event and send the email.   FWIW - I've written a lightweight Logging Framework that uses this same principle to write error logs to a custom object.   [Logging Framwork GitHub project](https://github.com/bobbywhitesfdc/LoggingFramework)

Comment: This is a good one, Thanks!